# Optimal camera focus mode android java

Tags: java, focus, android-camera

I have android application that use the phone camera.

First the camera opened, I want to try to use "Autofocus" mode and "Macro" mode and choose by code the best focus that I get.

I would like to ask 2 things:

1. Is there an internal parameter that give the focus score?
2. Is there a known algorithm that gives the focus score(the algorithm should not be complex, because I do it in real time on 1080p video).

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

I know a bunch of links is not usually helpful, but I don't have time to go through all the pages.  I figure something is better than nothing :)

This is the link for the [android.hardware.camera2.params](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/package-summary.html) package summary.  I wasn't able to find anything like what you are looking for, but that's a good place to start.

Another person had a similar question on the Android Enthusiasts SE site:  Can [I manually focus the camera on my Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2042/can-i-manually-focus-the-camera-on-my-android-phone)

And last, but not least: There seems to be quite a bit of relevant info at the [XDA Developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=630989).

Good Luck!   I'm a photographer myself, so this seems like an interesting project.